# .net / java class with mp4 download like StreamTransport

Tags: java, .net, download, mp4

I'm looking for a way to automatically download mp4 videos from a webpage. The freeware tool StreamTransport does a very good job, I add a web url and StreamTransport shows me the (very crypted) url and allows to download the video. So far, so good. The problem is, there are A LOT of videos I want to download, so manually click on each link will cost half of my life ;).

Does anyone of you knows a class or something like that (java or .net would be great) which could help me realizing this? In best I case I pass a URL and get the videos back. Coding a whole downloader for myself will probably cost me as much time as clicking each url ;).

If there isn't a Class, could you imagine a way realizing it with StreamTransport (like "control" StreamTransport with another tool)?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is what I found out so far:

It turned out, that the videos I wanted to download are rtmp streams. There is an XML configuration file for the web flash player which includes the rtmp url. Using rtmpdump (http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) does the trick and downloads the video.

In my opinion I have 2 options:

1. Use console app rtmpdump and try to "interact" with my tool
2. Find an easy-to-use library which can download mp4 videos by an rtmp url.  

Does anyone have an idea?